# JavaScript Variable Assignment in an Object

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this code? obj.bVar is undefined here, why is that? How do I assign the value of aVar to bVar?

```
var obj = {
    aVar: 15,
    bVar: this.aVar // This is undefined
};

console.log(obj.aVar);
console.log(obj.bVar);
```

Comment: The value of `this` depends on how the function containing the above code is called. If it is in global scope, `this` will be the `window` object.

Comment: Lots and lots of info available on this on SO, do a search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), in JavaScript, refers to the current scope, which is either a function call or the global scope.

Here, `this` is the global scope, that is `window` (apart if you're doing this in a function).

Here's a solution :

```
var obj = {
    aVar: 15
};
obj.bVar = obj.aVar;
```

Another one (that may or not be relevant, depending on the context of your application) would be to use a constructor :

```
function Obj(){
   this.aVar = 15;
   this.bVar = this.aVar;
}
var obj = new Obj();
```

Comment: Or the verbose: `bVar: (function() { return this.aVar; }).call(obj)`

Comment: @David Well, this too requires you create obj before you set bVar

Comment: As the function is immediately called, you need obj to exist, you can't do it before the assignement.

Comment: Forget it, my console was running tricks on me :) It wasn’t a good alternative anyway.